# Y axis in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, axis

I am trying to change my y axis scale.Indeed, Python puts my numbers into scientific notation. I want to stay with my original numbers.

This is my code:

```
Data = [['01',  float(18535404.0)],['02', float(3460047.0)], 
        ['03', float(3924627.0)],['04',float(3377404.0)],
        ['05',float(4006194.0)],['06',float(11077562.0)],
        ['07',float(2097105.0)],['08',float(2042300.0)],
        ['09',float(899693.0)],['10',float(7598384.0)],
        ['11',float(998367.0)]] 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
DataFrame3 = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=['Month', 'Sum'])
# print dataframe.
DataFrame3
plt.bar(DataFrame3['Month'],DataFrame3 ['Sum'] ,color=(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
```

I would like these numbers on my y axis:

```
18535404.0,3460047.0,3924627.0;....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, floating numbers are truncated to lower decimals, and then parsed.
If you want to exactly use the numbers as they are, try converting them to string.

```
str(num)
```

Your code will become:

```
Data = [['01', str(18535404.0)], ['02', str(3460047.0)], ['03', str(3924627.0)],['04',str(3377404.0)],['05',str(4006194.0)],['06',str(11077562.0)], ['07',str(2097105.0)],['08',str(2042300.0)],['09',str(899693.0)],['10',str(7598384.0)],['11',str(998367.0)]]


DataFrame3 = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=['Month', 'Sum'])


plt.bar(DataFrame3['Month'],DataFrame3 ['Sum'] ,color=(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib has a function called `ticklabel_format` that can be used for this.

Adding the following line (before `plt.show()`) will remove the scientific notation.

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

For more info, please refer the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format.html).